# How to identify the links inside a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a DataFrame of orders with a contract number

| Orders | Contract |
| --- | --- |
| Order_1 | Contract_1 |
| Order_1 | Contract_2 |
| Order_2 | Contract_1 |
| Order_2 | Contract_2 |

A contract can be linked to several orders.
An orders can be linked to several contracts.

I want to know all the links between the contracts, namely a DataFrame with all the contracts in index, and the linked contracts in the others columns.

desired output

| Contract_source | Contract_link |
| --- | --- |
| Contract_1 | Contract_2, Contract_3 |
| Contract_2 | Contract_1, Contract_3 |
| Contract_3 | Contract_1, Contract_2 |
| Contract_4 | Contract_8 |

or maybe

| Contract_source | Contract_link_1 | Contract_link_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contract_1 | Contract_2 | Contract_3 |
| Contract_2 | Contract_1 | Contract_3 |
| Contract_3 | Contract_1 | Contract_2 |
| Contract_4 | Contract_8 |  |

I have created a DataFrame with the index as contracts, and the orders in the column :

```py
df_po = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,['Contract Nbr', 'Order']].groupby(by='Order')\
    ['Contract Nbr'].apply(lambda x : list(x.unique()))).reset_index()
```

| Orders_source | Contract_link |
| --- | --- |
| Order_1 | Contract_1, Contract_2 |
| Order_2 | Contract_3, Contract_4 |

I have also created a DataFrame with the index as orders, and the contracts in the column :

```py
df_contract = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,['Contract Nbr', 'Order']].groupby(by='Contract Nbr')\
    ['Order'].apply(lambda x : x.unique())).reset_index()
```

| Contract_source | orders_link |
| --- | --- |
| Contract_1 | Order_1 , Order_2 |
| Contract_2 | Order_3, Order_4 |

But I struggle to replace the orders in df_contract with the contracts of df_contracts

I have created a dictionary to replace the orders with the contracts:

```py
dict_orders_to_contract = zip(df_po['Order'], df_po['Contrct Nbr'])
```

And I have tried this :

```
df_contract['count PO'] = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,['Contract Nbr', 'Order']].groupby(by='Contract Nbr')\
    ['Order'].apply(lambda x : x.unique().replace(dict_orders_to_contract ))).reset_index()['Order']
```

Comment: Where are Contract_3, Contract_4 and Contract_8 in your input?

Comment: Also, can the identifiers in "Orders" and "Contract" overlap?

Comment: If your code is not reproducible, hard to get an answer. make completeness of reproducibility of your code in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem, you can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to solve it.

Assuming this input:

```
    Orders    Contract
0  Order_1  Contract_1
1  Order_1  Contract_2
2  Order_2  Contract_1
3  Order_2  Contract_2
4  Order_2  Contract_3
5  Order_4  Contract_4
6  Order_4  Contract_8
```

Which translates into the following graph:

[image]

You can use:

```
import networkx as nx

# groupby order and collect contracts
s = df.groupby('Orders')['Contract'].agg(set)

# form a graph from the order groups
# this will merge the common contracts
G = nx.compose_all(map(nx.path_graph, s))

# identify the connected components
groups = {n: g-{n} for g in nx.connected_components(G) for n in g}

# craft the output
out = (pd.DataFrame({'Contract_source': df['Contract'].unique()})
         .assign(Contract_link=lambda d: d['Contract_source'].map(groups))
      )
```

Output:

```
  Contract_source             Contract_link
0      Contract_1  {Contract_3, Contract_2}
1      Contract_2  {Contract_1, Contract_3}
2      Contract_3  {Contract_1, Contract_2}
3      Contract_4              {Contract_8}
4      Contract_8              {Contract_4}
```

Alternative output format:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Contract_source': df['Contract'].unique()})
out = out.join(
 pd.DataFrame(out['Contract_source'].map(groups).tolist())
   .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Contract_link_{x+1}')
)
```

Output:

```
  Contract_source Contract_link_1 Contract_link_2
0      Contract_1      Contract_3      Contract_2
1      Contract_2      Contract_1      Contract_3
2      Contract_3      Contract_1      Contract_2
3      Contract_4      Contract_8            None
4      Contract_8      Contract_4            None
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you ! I will investigate